# Convert W3C's EBNF to ANTLR

Tags: antlr, antlr4, bnf, ebnf, project-fluent

I want to generate a Swift parser from the [grammar](https://github.com/projectfluent/fluent/blob/master/spec/fluent.ebnf) which describes [FTL syntax](https://github.com/projectfluent/fluent#fluent-syntax-ftl).

Is there any tool to make the `EBNF -> ANTLR` conversion automatically? Or are these two grammar syntaxes at least convertible?

The grammar itself is autogenerated from the [set of rules](https://github.com/projectfluent/fluent/blob/master/syntax/grammar.js) written in JavaScript. The other possible solution is to update `rules -> EBNF` [serializer](https://github.com/projectfluent/fluent/blob/master/lib/serializer.js) to output ANTLR syntax. But I'm newbie into languages and not sure that could handle it.

Comment: This grammar does not define the division of labor between lexer and parser, nor does it follow a consistent naming convention to indicate the division. Therefore, in order to convert this to Antlr, you would need to define a partition of the symbols. Antlrvsix can fix indirect left recursion, but it's not present here. The "-" operator would have to be converted into a semantic predicate.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/blob/master/fluent/fluent.g4). Completely untested.

Comment: Although there is nothing intrinsically preventing the conversion of EBNF syntax to Antlr4 syntax, this grammar has no clear boundary between lexer and parser. To get it to "work", I changed the lexer to be a per-character lexer and convert all EBNF rules tp Antlr parser rules. There were a few other nasty issues that Antlr cannot handle well, e.g., EOF in lower-level rules. Although was a good exercise, it's clearly not a good fit for Antlr.

Comment: Thank you for such great work and explanations! 
To understand all the problemes I probably need to read ANTRL book. But for now, I decided to try porting reference parser by hand. It seems that existing libs use the same approach: custom parser on target language + comprehensive test suit for validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any tool to make the EBNF -> ANTLR conversion automatically?

AFAIK, there is no such tool.

> Or are these two grammar syntaxes at least convertible?

No. EBNF allows for indirect left recursive rules, which ANTLR does not support (it does support direct left recursive rules though).